# Program to force Windows Vista+ to stay awake if there's audio i/o

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sleep

I'm currently using a program called Shutter by den4b. Windows likes to sleep even when there's a cpu intensive task running in the background, so I use Shutter to control when the computer sleeps. I have it setup such that it will sleep after 5 minutes of inactivity(no mouse movement), low cpu usage for at least 10 seconds, low network activity for at least 10 seconds, and low disk utilization for at least 10 seconds. It has one issue though, and that is when say a flash video is playing, it will still go to sleep since the previous conditions are met. However, if I can run a program in the background to prevent Windows from sleeping if there's audio i/o, then this will solve my problem. I know utorrent has the ability to prevent Windows from sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried going to your advanced power settings and preventing sleep when sharing media?  Also changing your power settings when playing video.  Some media software has options to prevent sleep built in as well.

Comment: I already have that option set. The issue is when I'm in a web browser and playing audio or watching a video.